# Database write delayed in rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I'm using authlogic to generate a perishable token and send it on to the user for activation of his account, and send the mail later in a delayed job.  Like so:

```
  def deliver_activation_instructions!
    reset_perishable_token!
    Notifier.send_later(:deliver_activation_instructions, self)
  end
```

What I'm seeing is that the perishable token written by the 'reset_perishable_token' call is not the one that has been emailed to the user.  If I'm using send_later, is there a chance that the worker will pick up old values from the database?  I thought that the Notifier.send_later call would only occur after the token had been written....  Or is there something I don't understand about how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question, the problem was not a bad database write - it was that the authlogic library automatically updates the perishable token every time you save the database record.  I was sending the token, then saving the user record which reset the token!  There is a config setting that I needed:
disable_perishable_token_maintenance = true

That did the trick and fixed my bug